# Multiple Pagination on the same page

Tags: pagination, page-uri

How we can integrate multiple pagination on the same page. anybody have idea ?

I have integrate, but only first pagination is worked. You can see my script below:

```
     {exp:channel:entries channel="institutions" dynamic="no" paginate="bottom" paginate_base="/{freebie_1}/{freebie_2}/paginate" limit="5" disable="member_data" category="169"}
            <div class="organisation {switch='odd|even'} cf">
                <div class="content">
                    <h2><a href="{page_uri}">{title}</a></h2>
                    {if institution_website_address}<a class="website-link" href="{institution_website_address}" target="_blank">{institution_website_address}</a>{/if}
                </div>
                {paginate}
                  {pagination_links}
                      <div class="paging cf">
                        <span class="page-name">Page({current_page}):</span>
                          {first_page}
                                  <a href="{pagination_url}" class="first">First</a>
                          {/first_page}

                          {previous_page}
                                  <a href="{pagination_url}" class="prev">Prev</a>
                          {/previous_page}
                          <div class="pages">
                          {page}
                                  <a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number} {if current_page}current{/if}">{pagination_page_number}</a>
                          {/page}
                          </div>
                          {next_page}
                                  <a href="{pagination_url}" class="next">Next</a>
                          {/next_page}

                          {last_page}
                                  <a href="{pagination_url}" class="last">Last</a>
                          {/last_page}
                      </div>
                  {/pagination_links}
                {/paginate}
            </div>
            {/exp:channel:entries}

           {exp:channel:entries channel="institutions" dynamic="no" paginate="bottom" paginate_base="/{freebie_1}/{freebie_2}/paginate" limit="5" disable="member_data" category="177"}
                <div class="organisation {switch='odd|even'} cf">

                    <div class="content">
                        <h2><a href="{page_uri}">{title}</a></h2>
                        {if institution_website_address}<a class="website-link" href="{institution_website_address}" target="_blank">{institution_website_address}</a>{/if}
                    </div>
                    {paginate}
                      {pagination_links}
                          <div class="paging cf">
                            <span class="page-name">Page({current_page}):</span>
                              {first_page}
                                      <a href="{pagination_url}" class="first">First</a>
                              {/first_page}

                              {previous_page}
                                      <a href="{pagination_url}" class="prev">Prev</a>
                              {/previous_page}
                              <div class="pages">
                              {page}
                                      <a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number} {if current_page}current{/if}">{pagination_page_number}</a>
                              {/page}
                              </div>
                              {next_page}
                                      <a href="{pagination_url}" class="next">Next</a>
                              {/next_page}

                              {last_page}
                                      <a href="{pagination_url}" class="last">Last</a>
                              {/last_page}
                          </div>
                      {/pagination_links}
                    {/paginate}
                </div>
                {/exp:channel:entries}
```

FYI: EE:2.7.2 with structure

Thanks